# Working With Series in Reverse Order (Latest First)

Tags: pandas

How can I reverse sort order of DataSeries in Pandas so that I'm working with them in descending order?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
In [28]: s = pd.Series([20, 10, 30], ['c', 'a', 'b'])

In [29]: s
Out[29]:
c    20
a    10
b    30
dtype: int64
```

Sorting on the index

```
In [30]: s.sort_index(ascending=False)
Out[30]:
c    20
b    30
a    10
dtype: int64
```

sorting on the values

```
In [31]: s.sort()

In [32]: s[::-1]
Out[32]:
b    30
c    20
a    10
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to suggest some changes to the answer by [@Wouter Overmeire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16403442/working-with-series-in-reverse-order-latest-first/16412695#16412695):

```
In []: s = pd.Series([20, 10, 30], ['c', 'a', 'b'])
In []: s
Out[]:
c    20
a    10
b    30
dtype: int64
```

The `pandas.Series.sort()` method is [deprecated in Pandas 0.18.1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.Series.sort.html) but now [`pandas.Series.sort_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) can be used instead for (inplace or not) sorting.

```
s.sort_values()
```

The `sort_values` method has keywords to change to ascending or descending order: `ascending=True`, or to not sort inplace: `inplace=False`.

and the last line of code of the previous answer **is not for sorting by values** but to return a slice of the Series s starting from the bottom. The slicing method works as follows:

```
s[start:end:step]
```

In the previous answer's example the slice starts from the begining (start position left empty), ends at the end (end left empty) and it takes every value (step with absolute value 1) but starts from the bottom of the Series (step with minus sign "-")

```
In[]: s[::-1]
Out[]:
b    30
a    10
c    20
dtype: int64
```